# Detect in script when nodemon has detected change

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I would like to be able to open my browser with:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8888';
console.log('now visit: ');

var open = require('open');
open(url);
```

but only when I first run:

```
nodemon ./app.js
```

Not when changes are detected in the file. Does anybody have an idea if I can wrap this in a condition? Obviously a change is detected and the app.js reruns and opens a new tab in the browser again.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achive by opening new tab in browser on each file change? You want to refresh browser content to avoid clicking refresh button?

Comment: I wish to run nodemon ./app.js and it open up a new browser tab but on subsequent changes, just refresh the server without opening up a new tab

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your question. What about starting nodemon by another file which will also open a browser tab? You can use grunt or gulp for that or just simple javascript file.